# Laravel - showing only posts that are created today using carbon

Tags: php, laravel, admin

I need to show only posts that are created that same day for specific user, user ID. I'm using Laravel Carbon for that but nothing happens, I don't know where the problem is. Here is my code

Here is my `OptikaController` with two users and `Carbon`:

```
class OptikaController extends Controller
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth:admin');
        $this->middleware('role:super', ['only'=>'show']);
    }


    public function delta(){
        $date = new Carbon(request('date'));

        $posts = Post::where('user_id', Auth::id(1))
                ->whereDate('created_at','=',$date)
                ->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')
                ->paginate(30); //add {{ $posts->links() }} if paginate is enabled
        $user_id = auth()->user()->id;
        $user = User::find(1);
        return view('delta', compact('date', $date))->with('posts', $user->posts);
    }

    public function centar(){
        $user_id = auth()->user()->id;
        $user = User::find(2);
        return view('centar')->with('posts', $user->posts);
    }
}
```

So I add `Post::where('user_id', Auth::id(1))` and `$user = User::find(1);` to see all posts made today by that user id 1 but nothing happens.It's showing me all posts ever created and I need posts only created today or that day they are created. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code seems to be working just fine. However, you should return `$posts` not `$user->posts`, your return line should look like this.

```
return view('delta', compact('date', $date))->with('posts', $posts);
```

Also, you could safely remove these lines unless you'll need to pass the user to your views.

```
$user_id = auth()->user()->id;
$user = User::find(1);
```

So your code should look something like this:

```
$date = Carbon::parse(request('date'));

$posts = Post::where('user_id', User::find(1)->id)
    ->whereDate('created_at', '=', $date)
    ->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')
    ->paginate(30);

return view('delta')->with('date', $date)->with('posts', $posts);
```

Comment: Sir, I cannot tell you how grateful I am! You solved my problem, it took me a lot time and anxiety. Thank you very much Sir !!

Comment: Also `where('user_id', 1)`  should work since you are finding the user by id